# how to get facebook botmessage and reply in php

Tags: php

I could not get bot message though I set APP setting and Webhooks completed. My code is :

```
   <?php  
     $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
     $verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
     $accessToken =  "EAAEUuISGRawBAEny0arZBBWJeCPwOTQedR7OpZBNNBi0zA8NPhSadM610rvOKvg4DK3sabhJ7pzZBQ0GO8jZAbNZASHCeM3kMcXePLIRKGZADSS2sLOI9Ase4kD9DIqNVv6JaAosq0Rqdi0kzckYK7q1nWMYk4cNJcY05ocKxlIwZDZD";

    // Set this Verify Token Value on your Facebook App 
    if ($verify_token === 'Verifytoken') {
       echo $challenge;
    }
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    // Get the Senders Graph ID
    $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];

    // Get the returned message
    $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
    echo $message;

   //API Url and Access Token, generate this token value on your Facebook App  Page
   $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?  access_token='.$accessToken;

   //Initiate cURL.
   $ch = curl_init($url);

   //The JSON data.
   $jsonData = '{
      "recipient":{
          "id":"' . $sender . '"
       }, 
      "message":{
          "text":"The message you want to return"
        }
    }';

    //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    //Set the content type to application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:        application/json'));

    //Execute the request but first check if the message is not empty.
   if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])){
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
   }
```

Please Help to get bot message and reply.

My App image is :
   [image: This is app image]

Free hosting cpanel link is:

https://files.000webhost.com/

```
username = 'myfbbots'
password = 'asdf1234'
```

and site link to see site is `:myfbbots+.000webhost+.com`

Comment: Owooooooo its working. So can use it Boss